# How can I change Scala compiler options in Zeppelin for Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

When I run a paragraph in a note, I get something like this in the display.

```
warning: there were 3 deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
```

To remove that warning from appearing, I want to run the Scala compiler with `-deprecation` option, so that I can fix these warnings. But for that, I need to know where to change these compiler settings in Zeppelin, which is my question here.

Comment: How are you running zeppelin? Have you compiled it from source and started running it ?

Comment: No, I just use the the released 0.8.1 version.

Comment: You will have to build zeppelin from source as mentioned here - https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/setup/basics/how_to_build.html and provide the compiler options in maven. In a running zeppelin environment you cannot compile scala again as it runs as a separate process which "interpreter" interacts with.